# Do as Someone question

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

"There's work we can **do as doctors** to improve the experience for families as well as patients."

Hello, I want to know what "**do as doctors**" means.

I have no idea why "as" is placed there and what it has to do with "doctors" and "do" and that's what is making me confused.

"As such" is not the same as my question since it means "therefore".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meaning and usage of "as such"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13481/meaning-and-usage-of-as-such)

Comment: ...That's to say, your text could be rephrased to *We are doctors, and **as such** we have work we can to...* The [relevant definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as) for ***as*** being *in the capacity, character, condition, or role of* (example: *He works as an editor*).

Comment: I still don't understand.

Comment: Can I understand us "We are doctors, and there is things we can do what would doctors do because we are doctors to improve the experience of others.

Comment: Absolutely! Your English in the preceding comment has a few "mistakes", but it's obvious you understand how ***as*** is being used in the example you asked about. You might like to also think about contexts like ***As your doctor**, I must advise you to take the medicine I've prescribed, but **as your friend** I must say that because of the likely side-effects it would probably be better not to.* That's to say, you can even refer to yourself or someone else ***in two different "roles"*** within the same utterance.

Comment: More like "We are doctors, and the things can be done to families are in the capacity of our roles(doctor). also srry for making mistakes, i probably wrote that in a hurry. Am I correct?

Comment: Yeah - you're correct. But please don't apologize for possible shortcomings in how you're expressing yourself in comments here. The main thing is I can *understand* what you're saying (which is effectively proving to me that *you* now understand the specific usage you asked about). Learning how to use English "idiomatically" in all contexts would be a lifetime's work for most non-native speakers, but you're doing well if you can at least make yourself *understood* with whatever meaning you're trying to convey. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [definition of **as**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as), you'll find this:

> Definition of *as* (Entry 4 of 9)
>
> ...
>
> 2. : in the capacity, character, condition, or role of

This is exactly the sense of **as** that is being used in your example:

> There's work we can do **in our role of** doctors to improve the experience for families as well as patients.

Comment: Can you explain it more in-depth because I'm confused about "in our role of".

Comment: _As doctors_ or _in our role of doctors_ function as adverbial phrases, modifying the predicate "[work that] we can do to improve ... ". The implication is that _because_ we are doctors, we can improve this, or that we can improve it _by doing what doctors do_.